# ES6 Default Module Syntax with 6to5

Tags: javascript, amd, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Is it possible to recreate the following with ES6 module syntax?

```
var foo = {};
module.exports = foo;
```

ES6 has support for adding the declarative keyword to the expression, like so:

```
export var foo = 'bar';
```

However, when run through [6to5](https://6to5.org), this generates:

```
var foo = exports.foo = 'bar';
```

Is it possible to use this syntax in conjunction with the default keyword, in order to generate the top code snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must export `foo` entity with `default` keyword:

```js
var foo = {};
export default foo;
```

It will generate exactly what do you want.

**PS**: You can export only one `default` variable per module and can import it without curly brackets:

```
import foo from 'some_module';
```

If you're exporting multiple variables:

```
export var foo = 10;
export var boo = 'something';
```

Then you must import them using curly brackets:

```
import { foo, boo } from 'some_module';
```

In that case `6to5` will generate a little more complicated result than your example.

More about ES6 modules read [here](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)